# How to wrap_content or "fill available space" in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have this layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    ... 
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout >
```

This recyclerview is added to the "id/content" framelayout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager" />
```

It has the desirable effect that the recyclerview is placed at the bottom of the screen.

[image]

The problem arises when there are many viewholders in the recyclerview. I would like to leave some room at the top to still see the map (200dp margin).  I've tried lots of ways and can't seem to find an elegant solution. Essentially what I want is that the recyclerview will wrap_content until that content is too big. If the content is too big, I want the recyclerview to expand to fill the space it can, while leaving 200dp at the top. In iOS this would be possible using a >= 200 constraint. Is this possible on android? How?

Comment: So the map View is outside of the FrameLayout? And the 200dp margin doesn't work?

Comment: Take a look at [`BottomSheetBehavior`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior) to see if it will meet your needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah! I forgot to add a vertical constraint to the top. Changing the FrameLayout to this did the trick.

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appBarLayout"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Why do you need AppBarLayout when you are not using CoordinatorLayout, and why do you add the RecyclerView to FrameLayout when you can use the RecyclerView directly?

Comment: Good tip on using CoordinatorLayout instead. As for the framelayout, I'm reusing that recyclerview elsewhere, which is why it isn't added directly.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem comes from the hierarchy of your layouts.

Adding the RecyclerView to android.R.id.content adds it to the same level of the ConstraintLayout, maybe if you add it directly to the ConstraintLayout and apply to it some constraints, you can achieve What your want.

Although, [BottomSheetBehavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior) maybe be the component that you want to mimic?

Comment: Good tip on BottomSheetBehavior. I didn't know that existed.